# Using MAX_ORDER / Include mmzone.h

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel, include

According to https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt the `MAX_ORDER` macro can be used in user space programs. However, including `linux/mmzone.h` fails with no such file or directory.

How can I use the `MAX_ORDER` macro?

Comment: It seems like Linux doesn't have `mmzone.h` file in UAPI anymore. So documentation *might be* outdated. Which kernel version are you using?

Comment: What do you need `MAX_ORDER` for? I think that this constant could be removed from user-space access for a reason.

Comment: Right know I am working with a 3.10 kernel. I want to use `MAX_ORDER` to calculate block size as described in the document: `<block size> = <pagesize> << <max-order>`

Comment: ...And what do you need **block size** for? I mean, ask the actual question. It may not involve `MAX_ORDER` at all, in the end.

Comment: Block size is the size of blocks used for the `TPACKET_V3` ring buffer. Following the documentation, I want to maximize it's size, which would be the maximum contiguous physical region of memory allocated with calls to the `__get_free_pages()` function. To rephrase my question: How can I determine the maximal contiguous physical region of memory that can be allocated with `__get_free_pages()`?

Comment: You should edit your question and add this information there (and perhaps change question title). If you can't do that -- go ahead and create another question, asking the actual question (like you did in the last comment). And also you should mention that that should be done in user-space, rather than in kernel.

Comment: See [`net/packet/af_packet.c`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/packet/af_packet.c) in the kernel sources, especially the `alloc_one_pg_vec_page()` function. It simply tries to fulfill the allocation order necessary to satisfy the block size asked. In other words, **ask for the largest block size you benefit from, and if it fails, fall back to smaller block sizes until you succeed.**

Comment: @NominalAnimal: I would profit from the largest possible size. So with which value should I start?

Comment: Hi @JGras, there are lots of other things also not cleared to me for PACKET_MMAP (i.e. ZERO COPY packet receiving or transmission). Do you have any other good tutorials or links? I am interested to study more on it.

Comment: @JGras: I believe you are mistaken. The memory taken by the ring is unswappable, so allocating a very large ring when only a small portion of it is used is just wasteful. For example, Ethernet devices' IP packets fit well within a 2048-byte frame, so a block size of smallest power of two that is a multiple of page size should work (typically 4096, as in the documentation example). Furthermore, as each packet is accessed separately (by the kernel/HW), having more than one frame in each continuous block of pages brings no speedup.

Comment: @BrijeshValera: Unfortunately I haven't found any other documentation. To gather more information I had a look at other implementations like [netsniff-ng](https://github.com/netsniff-ng/netsniff-ng) and had a look into the kernel source itself.

Comment: For IP networking (IPv4 and IPv6), I can understand 65536-byte frames, but then I'd use one frame per block. For IPv6 jumbograms, you could start by trying the maximum frame and block size -- one frame per block -- of 4,294,967,296, then backing down until you succeed.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Regarding the use of memory: To capture about 10Gbps, which is my use case, I was told people use buffers of 128 to 256MB. Therefore my buffer will consist of multiple blocks. I am using TPACKET_V3. If I understood correctly, in this case frames of different sizes inside a block are supported but a frame cannot be part of two different blocks. To minimize unused space inside blocks, I would like to have as few blocks as possible. In other words the largest possible block size.

Comment: @JGras: Consider something like a 64k block size. Even if you wasted say 4k per block in unusable space, that's only 6.25%. Aiming for maximum block size possible will adversely affect the machine operation (due to lack of contiguous page groups (high order pages) causing unnecessary page reclaim etc.), Instead of aiming for "maximum possible", make it a tunable (admin-configurable parameter), and *benchmark* the results in practice!

Comment: My point is, you do not really have any reason to aim for the "maximum possible block size in all situations". Making these tunable for your application/service, with reasonable defaults (obtained via testing), then testing different values in different situations on practical use cases, will likely yield much, *much* better results. And your users will be happier, too.