# How to determine max continuous memory that can be allocated with __get_free_pages()?

Tags: c, linux, memory, linux-kernel

How can I determine (in user space) the maximal contiguous physical region of memory that can be allocated with `__get_free_pages()`?

The problem behind is described in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33219155/using-max-order-include-mmzone-h).

Comment: This is of no use, as the information can be outdated already before the funtion returned. Just alloc what you need. (and why would one care about physmem in userspace anyway? Looks like XY problem.

Comment: I don't alloc myself. It's a ring buffer allocated by the kernel but the user has to specify the layout.

Comment: @Olaf Looks like XY question to me, too.

Comment: @JGras Please describe the whole problem, with details. What you are trying to develop, and what is the issue on high level. It's much likely that you are assuming some solution and asking question about this solution. Instead let us see the whole picture and decide what is the actual issue and how it should be fixed.

Comment: The question looks strange, anyhow it looks like cat /proc/buddyinfo can show this

Comment: For those, who want to have more information: 1. Read my question. 2. Follow the link to the related question. 3. Follow the link to the documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/packet_mmap.txt). 4. Read the (relevant aspect of the) documentation (Hint: You may find it by searching for MAX_ORDER).

Comment: @AlexHoppus: Thanks! The first useful comment :)

Comment: You are expected to provide a comprehensive question, not just link to another question (which would make it a dup). Even worse, the linked "question" does not clarify what you are trying to do. To repeat: As give, it has a strong hautgout of a wrong approach.